# Additional SQL Server sample databases to practice with

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sample, demo

I'm helping a friend learn SQL, and need more databases to help him get more practice. 
We have of course AdventureWorks, Northwind, and Pubs.
Does anybody know of any other SQL databases samples that might be available to download? 
I know some sites have some databases where you can practice queries on the site, but I was looking for something he can run locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one called the Chinook Database.  It has scripts for SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer Compact.

http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=21111

As I find more, I'll post here.

Answer (score 4):

Try downloading and importing some of the free data sets the **Census bureau, US Geological Survey, National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration,** or other large data gathering agencies provide for free on the web.

Why not work with a billion record table of all the elevation points in the US?  Not only do you get the practice your DB skills, you can get real world types of indexing and performance issues.

Comment: Best idea so far, but I'm trying to be lazy and not invest any time other than download and make up some exercises.

Comment: There are sites out there that use publicly available data for sample code projects.  Too lazy to search for one specifically, but I know the census data has been used on sites such as CodeProject.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much better Idea to create a database from scratch ,Taking sample project say a simple inventory management system and then building tables finally creating then in db ,It would be much practical way to learn then to directly play with a ready made database.

Comment: I'm not getting paid to tutor him (so I don't want to build and define new databases), and he stills need practice with queries.  When he gets to design, yes, I might have him create some of these types of databases.